# Is a VM CPU reservation deducted from the cluster CPU usage?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

We recently have a high number of CPU reservations to be set on specific VMs due to vendor requirements. To be able to perform some capacity planning I'd like to know how these CPU reservations are reflected in the cluster statistics.

Say for example we have the following cluster stats:

[image: VMware cluster stats]

If we would now create VM CPU reservation of 10 GHz, would this deduct from the free CPU statistic resulting in 85.66 GHz free or not?

On some clusters where we want to make a reservation and where enough free CPU is available, we get the error message of insufficient resources available. So I guess the answer to my question above is: no. How can we perform some (basic) capacity planning for this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that under Monitor > Resource allocation > CPU I could see the amount available for reservation. This helps a lot!

[image]